# nonlinear gradient descent does not converge nicely

Tags: python, machine-learning, gradient-descent

I am doing a nonlinear gradient descent, the main part of code as follows:

```py
m = len(train_x)
Y = train_y
W = np.array([0] * 10, dtype='float')
# create new features from x
X = np.c_[
    np.ones(m), 
    train_x, 
    train_x ** 0.5, 
    train_x ** 2, 
    train_x ** 3,
    train_x ** 4,
    train_x ** 5, 
    train_x ** 6, 
    train_x ** 7,
    train_x ** 8,
]

# normalize
for wi in range(len(W)):
    X[:, wi] /= X[:, wi].max()


num_iters = 200
lr = 0.1
for i in np.arange(1, 1+num_iters):
    diff = X @ W - Y
    for wi in range(len(W)):
        # update using derivative
        k = diff if wi == 0 else diff * X[:, wi]
        W[wi] -= lr * np.sum(k) / m

    if i % 20 == 0:
        cost = np.square(diff).sum() / 2 / m
        print(f'iteration={i} cost={cost}')


y = X @ W
plt.scatter(train_x, y, color='red', label='predication')
plt.scatter(train_x, train_y, label='train data')
plt.scatter(test_x, test_y, label='test data')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

I get the following output:
[image: output image]
May I know what am I doing wrong here?
How can I get output fit to the curve?

#### update

I tried to randomize the initial weights but get some very similar results:

```py
W = np.array([np.random.rand() for _ in range(10)])
```

Comment: Seems it gets stuck in a local minimum. Try random initalization for the weights and increase the number of iterations.

Comment: It seems the loss is decreasing well enough.

Comment: @MustafaAydın Thanks for the suggestion, I tried it but get similar results

Comment: You can try decreasing the `lr`

Comment: @MdJohirulIslam I tried that as well, but get a similar result as well.Thanks